# Windows 10 Connection center: Directly connect to VPN

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I have two laptops, both with multiple VPN connections. One of them shows a "connect" button, when I click on the VPN connection in connection center, the other one directly redirects me to VPN Control Panel, where I have to click on the connection again and then can click on connect.
That is three more clicks and an additional window opening...

I'd like to have the "directly" connect option on the other laptop as well but could not find a registry entry / setting / whatever to do this. Any idea?

Here is how I'd like it to be:
[image: Here is how I'd like it to be]
Here is how it looks like:
[image: Here is how it looks like:]

The one where it works is 20H1, the other one is 21H1, but it did not work on this with earlier versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution that at least brings back the "Connect" button although it kinda "cripples" the interface, but at least it saves clicks:

1. Open regedit (WIN+R and type regedit.exe) Navigate to
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Control
   Panel\Settings\Network
2. Take ownership of the “Network” key/folder
   (right click, Permissions)
3. Select “Advanced” in the Permissions window
4. In the Advanced window, select “Change” where the owner field
   is (at the top of the window)
5. Type in your username and save your changes. Close the advanced window
6. Now select “Administrators” in the security tab Make sure “Full control” is selected, then apply changes
7. Now that’s done, double click “ReplaceVan” Change it’s value
   to 2

After that the design goes back to Windows 8 design, but at least the button is there. I still do not know, how it works on the other machine, but better than nothing.

[image: New / Old Network panel]